# Receiving int from AJAX request in Server

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, servlets

I sent an AJAX request to a server

In the body of the XMLHttpRequest() I sent:

```
XMLHttpRequest().send('action=dosomething&roomid=' + roomIDValue);
```

where roomIDValue is an int variable. I can parse the string that has "action" for a name in the server, but I can't seem to parse the roomid, can int values be passed through this string format? This is my current int parser code that does not work:

```
int plainroomID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("roomid"));
```

I am parsing action with this code:

```
String[] returnedaction = request.getParameterValues("action");
StringBuilder stringReturnedAction  = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < returnedactioN.length; i++) {
    stringReturnedAction.append(returnedaction [i]);
}

String actionValue =  stringReturnedAction.toString();
```

Comment: can you post code that you are using to parse 'action' and the error you are getting while parsing 'roomid'.

Comment: I just did right now

Comment: what is the error you are getting while parsing roomid. Aldo why have you used getParameter for roomid and getParameterValues for action,